Problem with HDI dataset
I am new  to Orange3. I am trying to follow the same steps in the following article https://orangedatamining.com/blog/data-mining-covid-19-epidemics-part-1/
But unfortunately the HDI dataset that is currently available on orange3 misses some variables such as the total population (it has only 53 out of 68 variables) . What can I do to access the HDI dataset (2016) ?
I appreciate any help in advance.
